# best backup strategy for laptop

Tags: backup

I have the following backup strategies(use one or combine multiples): I want to know if there are easier and more robust solutions.  are there additonal strategy I can use?

```
1. create a image dump onto an external disk.
2. windows built-in recovery and restore function
3. manual&automatic backup of important files onto external disk/cloud.
```

Comment: there's a load of questions here on the subject. Its also very subjective and depends on your OS, what kind of situations you are worried about etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to use option 1.

I personally use Acronis Backup and Recovery. Just image the entire contents of your system partition and these of your second one (if you have one).

You will even be able to boot from the external disk seeing your system as you left it when backing-up.